# Even boiler Unity Shader code is showing error

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I have a Unity Project with Android package installed trying to create shaders. I created a Shader, which is a Standard Surface Shader. The problem is that the default code itself shows errors. On the same project, other people do not face such issues, and I'm not sure what is causing it.

The first line itself which is

`Shader "Custom/SurfaceShader"`

shows the error:

```
found "Custom/SurfaceShader" but expected '<identifier>'.

Found "Custom/SurfaceShader" but expected ';'.

Unexpected token "Custom/SurfaceShader".
```

I can't figure out how to proceed as I cannot find anything on the web regarding this issue.

Here is the code:

```
Shader "Custom/SurfaceShader"
```

{
Properties
{
_Color ("Color", Color) = (1,1,1,1)
_MainTex ("Albedo (RGB)", 2D) = "white" {}
_Glossiness ("Smoothness", Range(0,1)) = 0.5
_Metallic ("Metallic", Range(0,1)) = 0.0
}
SubShader
{
Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
LOD 200

```
    CGPROGRAM
    // Physically based Standard lighting model, and enable shadows on all light types
    #pragma surface surf Standard fullforwardshadows

    // Use shader model 3.0 target, to get nicer looking lighting
    #pragma target 3.0

    sampler2D _MainTex;

    struct Input
    {
        float2 uv_MainTex;
    };

    half _Glossiness;
    half _Metallic;
    fixed4 _Color;

    // Add instancing support for this shader. You need to check 'Enable Instancing' on materials that use the shader.
    // See https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/GPUInstancing.html for more information about instancing.
    // #pragma instancing_options assumeuniformscaling
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_START(Props)
        // put more per-instance properties here
    UNITY_INSTANCING_BUFFER_END(Props)

    void surf (Input IN, inout SurfaceOutputStandard o)
    {
        // Albedo comes from a texture tinted by color
        fixed4 c = tex2D (_MainTex, IN.uv_MainTex) * _Color;
        o.Albedo = c.rgb;
        // Metallic and smoothness come from slider variables
        o.Metallic = _Metallic;
        o.Smoothness = _Glossiness;
        o.Alpha = c.a;
    }
    ENDCG
}
FallBack "Diffuse"
```

}

Comment: Can you share the entire class or a snippet of code?

Comment: I've noticed this too and there are a few Unity forum posts (but no answers). Just ignore it though, it's doing no harm. I think the way the project is analysed by VS in recent versions of Unity means they are not found - as the errors suggest - but they have no effect.

Comment: @tomerpacific shared the code via editing the original post.

Comment: @Absinthe Can I download something like VS 2012 or something similar to fix this issue? I'm new so debugging or even testing if its working is already a pain for me